# datatemplate issue in silverlight(when assigning value to property)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Consider this code:

```
public class customlistbox : ListBox
{
    public customlistbox()
    { 
        this.itemtemplate = this.gettemplate(); 
    }

    private string gettemplate() 
    { 
        return ".......<locall:CustomGrid Background='" + Background.Color + "' ParentReference='" + this + "' > "....." 
    }
}
```

'ParentReference' is a property which is of type customlistbox. but i give ParentReference='" + this + "', it shows error. how can i give value for 'ParentReference' in such case??

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because you're passing a string to a property which is a `DataTemplate`.

You could try using a [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to load the string as xaml, but for the sake of just specifying a color within the template I'd define the template in XAML and then bind the value you want for the color.